# Android Material floating action button expanding menu effect

Tags: android, button

Could someone tell me the name of the effect in the pink button (like the FAB button)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Circular Floating Action Menu. I'm not sure if it's supported directly from Google APIs, but I was looking into it just yesterday and I found this awesome git repo.

[Take a look here](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu)